# display input text in image - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to display input text over image by JavaScript. mean any user input text will appears in image. but all i  get it  [object HTMLInputElement]

html

```
<body>
  <div class="congrat">
      <img src="img/congrat.png" alt="">

      <h3 id="text">hi iam here</h3>
  </div>  

  <div class="name">
    <button  onclick="ReplaceText()">Click Me!</button>
    <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
    <input dir="rtl" type="text" id="name">
  </div>
  

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

JavaScript code

```
const Text = document.getElementById('text');
const Input = document.getElementById('name');

function ReplaceText(){
    if( Input.textContent.value == 0){
        console.log(1)
      
    }else{
       Text.innerHTML = Input
    }
}
```

when clicked in button its shown me ..[object HTMLInputElement]

Comment: use . value for fetching values

Answer (score 2):

1. Please use camelCase for variable names, it's standard.
2. This is vulnerable to a HTML injection. Use `innerText` for user-inputted values.
3. `Input` is an instance of `HTMLInputElement`. It has a `.textContent` property, but stringified (as you did) it becomes the `[object X]` placeholder. Use `.value` instead.

```js
const text = document.getElementById('text');
const input = document.getElementById('name');

function replaceText(){
    if (!input.value) {
        console.log(1)
      
    } else {
       text.innerText = input.value;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="congrat">
      <img src="img/congrat.png" alt="">

      <h3 id="text">hi iam here</h3>
  </div>  

  <div class="name">
    <button  onclick="replaceText()">Click Me!</button>
    <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
    <input dir="rtl" type="text" id="name">
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

the Input will return the object element and this object have some properties like value to get value of this object.

**edit by** @0xLogN:

avoid use innerHTML with input to avoid js injection, use innerText

```js
const Text = document.getElementById('text');
const Input = document.getElementById('name');

function ReplaceText(){
    if( Input.textContent.value == 0){
        console.log(1)
      
    }else{
       Text.innerText = Input.value
    }
}
```

[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/prop_text_value.asp)

Comment: Also vulnerable to HTML injection, and "textContent.value" shouldn't be used!

Comment: HTML injection would be a user writing `</h1><script>CODE</script><h1>` to allow dynamic code injection which is a bad thing (especially with server-based ENVs). Use `innerText` instead,

Comment: Yes i just tried out , it's vulnerable to XSS too

Comment: @0xLogN thanks alot for your help, i will edit it now